# Error in installing Shipstation Plugin for Magento 2 Store

Tags: magento2

I am installing  Auctane-ShipStation module for Magento 2.3.4 by referring the following site https://help.shipstation.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025855652-Magento#connect-a-magento-store-to-shipstation-0-1.
There is no option to directly download the shipstation module. They are asking to install it via composer. I am using " composer require auctane/api:2.2.9 " command to install it but it is giving error " [InvalidArgumentException] Could not find a matching version of package auctane/api. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability( stable). "

Comment: What if you try `composer require auctane/api:v2.2.9`?

Comment: No I have tried it this way also still gives same error

Comment: @ManjushaKolhe Have you got this working ?

Answer (score 0):

Open your `composer.json` if that package has no stable version then you have to change your minimum-stability to dev.

```
https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability
```